# Wrong addition in C++

Tags: c++

```
double *out;
int size = size1+size2;
string s = "";
int c = 0;
int curr = 0;
for(int i=size-2; i >= 0; i--) {
    cout << "\nP: " << out[i]/size << "\n";
    cout << "Carry: " << c <<"\n";
    curr = out[i]/size + c;
    s += char(curr%10 + '0');
    cout << "Out: " << curr <<"\n";
    c = curr / 10;
}
```

In this snippet I am trying to add "P" (`out[I]/size`) and "Carry" (`c`) into "Out" (`curr`). As you can see in the output for 41 and 2, the addition comes out to be 42. Can someone explain how?

Output:

P: 20
Carry: 0
Out: 20

P: 41
Carry: 2
Out: 42

P: 37
Carry: 4
Out: 40

P: 43
Carry: 4
Out: 47

P: 49
Carry: 4
Out: 53

P: 83
Carry: 5
Out: 88

Comment: This sounds like floating-point error.  What is the datatype of `out`?  What is the datatype of `size`?

Comment: Added datatypes to the question.

Comment: You did not initialized `out`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking past the fact that this is not a well-formed code example due to `out` being an uninitialized pointer, I'm sure you just chucked it there for illustration instead of actually *demonstrating* your actual code.

But anyway, if you are doing floating-point division (which is the case with `out[i] / size`) then when you output that value with `std::cout` it will round it to whatever the output precision is.  In reality it may be slightly less or slightly more than 41.

Similarly, when you take that value and add `c` you have the same thing: a floating point value that might be slightly more or slightly less than 43.  When you now truncate that to an integer then if it's less than 43 the value will become 42.

Try this:

```
curr = static_cast<int>(std::round(out[i] / size + c));
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad code illustration, but your solution worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `out` is not initialized. So your code has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (since that variable contains some unknown / unpredictable pointer).

If you compiled with  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as  `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`, you should get some warnings.

You could consider coding

```
int size = size1+size2;
double* out = new double [size];
```

Then compile your program with all warnings and debug info, and use a debugger (like [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)) to understand the behavior of your executable.

Take more time to read some good [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), and some good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html)

Be sure to read the documentation of your C++ compiler. For GCC it is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/). For [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) it is [there](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html).

You could later read some C++ draft standard, like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or buy the latest C++ standard from [ISO](https://www.iso.org/).

You could find many open source projects coded in C++ (e.g. [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), [Ghudi](https://project.inria.fr/gudhi/), [Qt](https://qt.io/), [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) and many others....). Take some time to study their source code (for inspiration)

Regarding floating point operations don't forget to read the [Floating Point Guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/).

Consider (if so allowed) using the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) on your code.